# SQL Return a clean value

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I'm using this code :

```
$query = $conn->query('SELECT content FROM project WHERE id=30');
                    $result = $query->fetchColumn();

echo serialize($result);
```

It should return : I love puppies , as it is in the table but it returns s:24:"I love puppies";

So I basically want it to return a clean value without the s:24 or "

Comment: `'SELECT \`content\` FROM \`project\` WHERE \`id\`=30'` and you are using `fetchColumn()` which is why it is not a "clean value"

Comment: You need to get row, not column. Use fetchRow()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `serialize` function in a string, you'll get the format:

`s:size:value`

the first `s` standing for String, and the size in you case is 24. You can check comment http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php#66147 for more details.

So, if you want just the value, you can just avoid calling `serialize`:

```
$query = $conn->query('SELECT content FROM project WHERE id=30');
$result = $query->fetchColumn();
echo $result;
```

Comment: Thank you , I just overcomplicated it

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$query = $conn->query('SELECT content FROM project WHERE id=30');
$result = $query->fetch_object()->content;

echo $result;
?>
```